Can't use ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE for locking table in Spring boot app
On my project i use QueryDSL for access to Postgres db. Recently i got task to set lock on table so only one instance of app can use table (locks on rows can't be used). I tries to use in code ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE lock but failed.
In Sql editor of Dbeaver my request is simple:
BEGIN;
    LOCK TABLE findata.tax_calc_buffer IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    SELECT findata.tax_calc_buffer.tax_calc_buffer_id , findata.tax_calc_buffer.client_id 
    FROM findata.tax_calc_buffer
    LIMIT 1000;
    DELETE FROM findata.tax_calc_buffer WHERE findata.tax_calc_buffer.client_id in('result set of select');
END;

It works as expected, there is nothing complex.
But i struggle to implement this query into queryDSL code.
Fist problem queryDSL does not have locking methods. I workaround it with Preparedstatment which locks table before further queries of transaction.
For now i ended with this method, which satisfies task requirements:
@Transactional()
    public List<Integer> getIdsForRecalculation(Integer batchSize) {
        List<Integer> idsToRecalc = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> bufferIdsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection connection = postgreSQLQueryFactory.getConnection();
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName() + UUID.randomUUID();
            log.info("Thread {} tries to set lock", threadName);
            PreparedStatement lockStatement = connection.prepareStatement("LOCK TABLE findata.tax_calc_buffer IN EXCLUSIVE MODE");
            lockStatement.executeUpdate();
            log.info("Lock is set by thread {}", threadName);

            List<Tuple> recordsToRecalc = postgreSQLQueryFactory
                    .select(taxCalcBuffer.taxCalcBufferId, taxCalcBuffer.clientId)
                    .from(taxCalcBuffer)
                    .limit(batchSize)
                    .fetch();

            recordsToRecalc.forEach(tuple -> {
                bufferIdsToDelete.add(tuple.get(taxCalcBuffer.taxCalcBufferId));
                idsToRecalc.add(tuple.get(taxCalcBuffer.clientId));
            });

            postgreSQLQueryFactory.delete(taxCalcBuffer)
                    .where(taxCalcBuffer.taxCalcBufferId.in(bufferIdsToDelete))
                    .execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error while getting client ids for tax recal {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return idsToRecalc;
    }

But originally i wanted to use ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE for locking, but with it code didn't executes after lock was set. I'm curious why, because as i understand Spring whole method should be executed as one transaction. But it seemed like after lockStatement.executeUpdate(); line transaction were commited and further select can't be executed.
I tried different approaches - write method using only jdbc, setting autocommits to off and commit manually - always same result, lock blocks further queries.
